# accepting an argument and conditions Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I´m trying to make a script which takes a single command-line argument. Then it looks on the argument and if its a directory name, it just prints that this directory exists. If its a file name, it prints out the file exists. Otherwise, it tries to create a directory with this name and tests whether it was successful and reports this on the standard output.

my code is:

```
while read argument; do
     if [ $argument -d ]; then
        echo "Directory exists"
     elif [ $argument -e ]
        echo "File exists"
     else
        mkdir $argument
        if [ $argument -d]; then
           echo "Directory was created"
        else
           echo "Error while creating the directory"
        fi
     fi
done
```

Then I run the code `./file_name.sh argument`. If I run the code like this, I get an error on line 8, which is just "else". While is probably not necessary here, it was the first option how to accept an argument from the command line that came to my mind.

Comment: Copy paste your script in this site and fix the errors shown - https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: `if [ $argument -d ]` What do you think that does?!

Comment: You’re missing a `then` after the `elif`.

Comment: `read` reads from STDIN, not command line arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you  mentioned, you need single command line argument, So no need to loop

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ -z "$1" ]]; then 
  echo "Help : You have to pass one argument" 
  exit 0 
fi  
if [[ -d "$1" ]]; then 
    echo "Directory exists"
elif [[ -f "$1" ]]; then 
    echo "File exists"
else
    mkdir "$1"
    if [ -d "$1" ]; then
       echo "Directory was created"
    else
       echo "Error while creating the directory"
    fi
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if [ -d $1 ]; then
        echo "Directory exists"
elif [ -e $1 ]; then
        echo "File exists"
else
        mkdir $1
        if [ -d $1 ]; then
           echo "Directory was created"
        else
           echo "Error while creating the directory"
        fi
fi
```

I made up this solution thanks to the links provided, thank you.

Comment: Quote your variables! As mentioned before; https://www.shellcheck.net is your friend.